# How getFragmentManager() works internally on Orientation change

Tags: android, android-fragments

So, when the orientation changes we can add setRetainInstance(true) this will save the fragment from being destroyed on orientation change but getFragmentManger will give different instance of fragmnent manager. So how this works internally. how different fragment manager come to know that this fragment should be used. What are the fragment lifecycle methods will be called?

Comment: it depends on your pager adapter, which one you inquiring about?

Comment: No pager adapter asking simple activity and 1 fragment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No magic there.

`FragmentManager` saves the state when `FragmentActivity`'s [`onSaveInstanceState()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.java#475) is called in the `Parcel`.

Then the state is being fetched from the bundle of `FragmentActivity`, from [`onCreate()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.java#191).

You can view actual saving and restoring implementation code in [`FragmentManagerImpl::saveAllState()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/support/v4/app/FragmentManager.java#FragmentManagerImpl.saveAllState%28%29) and [`FragmentManagerImpl::restoreAllState()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/support/v4/app/FragmentManager.java#FragmentManagerImpl.restoreAllState%28android.os.Parcelable%2Cjava.util.ArrayList%29).